# C++/CLI Winform - Is it possible to have 1 event handler for multiple textboxes

Tags: winforms, textbox, c++-cli

Im trying to limit the user input to float or integer by using this function I found from another post.

```
private: System::Void keypressValidation(System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        // Only allow 1 decimal point
        if (e->KeyChar == '.')
        {
            if (textBox->Text->Contains(".") && !textBox->SelectedText->Contains("."))
            {
                e->Handled = true;
            }
        }
        // Accepts only digits and Backspace keypress
        else if (!Char::IsDigit(e->KeyChar) && e->KeyChar != 0x08)
        {
            e->Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Right now I have 8 textboxes on my UI and I created 8 different keypress event handler for every individual textbox.

```
private: System::Void txtN3_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtN3, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtN2_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtN2, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtN1_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtN1, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtN0_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtN0, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtD3_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtD3, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtD2_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtD2, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtD1_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtD1, e);
    }
    private: System::Void txtD0_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
        keypressValidation(txtD0, e);
    }
```

But later on in my project I will have around 64 textboxes and I find it too tedious to have an event handler for every textboxes.
Is there a method which will make this more compact such as only having one event handler for multiple textboxes?

Comment: Yes, that's why they call it a MultiCast delegate.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: No, this has nothing to do with multicast

Comment: To elaborate:  Multicast causes one event to call multiple functions.  OP needs multiple events to call one function.  It is the opposite of multicast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can do this with only a single handler function.  First you must deal with the small difference between the functions:

```
void txtGeneric_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e)
{
    keypressValidation(safe_cast<TextBox^>(sender), e);
}
```

Then it is a simple matter in the designer of wiring up the event on every textbox to this unified handler.  Instead of double-clicking on the handler entry in the event list, use the drop-down to select the existing function.

[image]

Another option is to remove all the handlers in the designer and wire them up at runtime, as suggested by @EylM.  Note that his loop will only work if every single textbox on the form is treated the same way, if you have even one or two that aren't part of the pattern, you'll need more complicated filtering.

Answer (score -1):

My preferred way would be to iterate over all textboxes in the Form and bind a single event handler.
Here is the sample code in C++/CLI:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    for each (Control ^ ctrl in this->Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl->GetType() == TextBox::typeid)
        {
            ctrl->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private: System::Void textBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e)
{

}
```

Comment: @Jason: You can't use `keypressValidation` as the event handler since it has the wrong argument types.  You do still need a tiny "glue" function, as shown in my answer, to be the actual event handler and call `keypressValidation`.  But you only need one no matter how many textboxes.